# Getting only a small part from image src path using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

So far, I managed to do this:

```
final Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect(strings[0])
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(5000).get();

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("data:image.*");
            Elements scripts = doc.select("script");
            for (Element script : scripts) {
                if (script.html().contains("data:image") && script.html().contains("dimg_"))
                {
                    Log.i("INSIDE", imgurl);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(script.html());
                    if(matcher.find())
                    {
                        imgurl = script.html().substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                        Log.i("REGEX", imgurl);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and it does work out quite well, but it stops on 3/4 of the way for some reason.

it gives me this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

but I need more than that :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

**I even tried using this pattern of regex - "data:image.*?(?=\")" for reading until commas but it fails.**

Comment: What's your selector to select `image`?

Comment: Elements images = ImageBlock.select("img[id^=dimg_]"); and after that I take the first image I see:
Element image = images.first();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you want is inside some javascript tag. Try to extract that tag:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=885178979613&num10";
    final Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect(url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0")
            .timeout(5000).get();
    Elements scripts = doc.select("script");
    for (Element script : scripts) {
        if (script.html().contains("data:image")) {
            System.out.println(script.html());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

And then extract it with a regex, like `'data:image.*'`.
You can see an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/VdE6SN/1/).

**EDIT**
 1. Change the regex pattern line into `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("data:image.*?'");`
It adds an extra apostrophe. You can avoid it by substracting 1 from `matcher.end()` (I guess there's a cleaner way, but I'm not regex expert).
 2. I run the above code (with the different pattern of course) on Eclipse and I get the expected output. I guess you're using Android studio - maybe there's an issue with the output buffer length, so it only prints part of the string. Your output has 4060 chars and the expected has 6276 chars - check the actual string's length with `.length()` and see if I'm right.

Comment: Hi thanks :), I've edited the question still got some minors problems left

Comment: I do use android studio, and it's indeed 6276 char long, another problem is that I scrape inside "doInbackground"  method and then updating the "imgurl" variable and then on the activity that called this async task, I use Picasso library with "imgurl" that I've just fetched to draw that image on certain image view.  The problem now is that I'm not seeing an image whatsoever.

Comment: Picasso.get().load(Scrape_Asynctasks.imgurl).into(cameraActivity.imageView);

Comment: Well, it looks like a different problem. I think you should open a new question about it, since it looks like your question (about how to get the data) is solved :)